# Cannot stop HwndSource Hook properly

Tags: c#, .net

How can I stop the hook properly? Because of the hook I cannot close the application properly.

Code Behind:

```
protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
            IntPtr windowHandle = (new WindowInteropHelper(this)).Handle;
            HwndSource src = HwndSource.FromHwnd(windowHandle);
            src.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
        }

 private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            // Handle WM_DEVICECHANGE
            if (msg == 0x0219)
            {
RunService();
    }
```

I have writen something like below, but it won't stop the application properly:

```
private void StopHook()
        {
            IntPtr windowHandle = (new WindowInteropHelper(this)).Handle;
            HwndSource src = HwndSource.FromHwnd(windowHandle);
            src.RemoveHook(new HwndSourceHook(this.WndProc));
        }

protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnClosing(e);
            StopService(); // to clear thread
            StopHook();
        }
```

---

UPDATED:

I think RunService is causing the problem, but I am using StopService to close all thread.

Comment: You don't have to remove the hook.  What else is going on in that WndProc method?

Comment: Inside WndProc I am running some thread to do some work. When window closing I will run a function to clear the thread.